# Format multiple tables on Tableau dashboard

Tags: formatting, tableau-api

I have 12 sheets in Tableau and require to display them on a dashboard as an overall summary which should have 3 categories which 4 tables in each. With 10 records per table at most.

Attempted to align them in a horizontal container though they are not aligned correctly. Distributing them evenly looks better though when I create the next container it’s not aligned to the one above. Also tried a vertical container in a horizontal with a similar outcome.

How would I make them into 4 table containers and have them aligned with the others below?